# Is it idiomatic to say "The sentence is stating a fact"?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language

The sun rises in the east, everyone knows it.

When I say the sentence "The sun rises in the east", I am stating a fact.

Is it idiomatic to say,

> **The sentence** is stating a fact.

Although, it is actually me stating a fact through that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that although there are multiple uses of the phrase **the sentence states**, it can find none of **the sentence is stating**.

In real life people are far more likely to say that **the sentence is correct/factual** than either **the sentence states** or **is stating**.

So although the sentence is grammatically correct, I doubt that it could be said to be idiomatic.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+sentence+states%2Cthe+sentence+is+stating

Comment: While it is not necessarily common, that does not mean it is not idiomatic.  I don't think most people would find that statement to be awkward or unnatural in any way, so I think it's reasonable to say that it *is* idiomatic, even if it's not common.  Also, "is factual" and "is stating a fact" do not have exactly the same nuance.  "is factual" is fairly neutral, but saying it "is stating a fact" is a bit more assertive and implies (to me, at least) that the fact is being stated for some deliberate reason.

Comment: @Foogod It's good to hear the other side of the argument!